# SwiftUI context menu trigger by left click on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a gear button on my view, when user click it I want to show a menu of buttons. It seems the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(menuitems:) is designed for this task but only right click can trigger the context menu.

How can I trigger the `contextMenu` by left-click on macOS? Thanks!

Comment: Use Menu instead of contextMenu. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/63933231/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. I already tried the `Menu` but the hit area of the Menu is a bar and I want to trigger the menu only by clicking the gear icon itself.

Answer (score 19):

You can use a specific menu style for that type of UI. If you want to hide the indicator, just put in false.

```swift
Menu("Label") {
      Button("Buttons") { }
}
.menuStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuStyle())
.menuIndicator(.hidden)
.fixedSize() // Otherwise will be the width of your menu options.
```